# Compiling with mpicc (MPICH2) and pthread_barrier (-lpthread)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, pthreads, mpich

I have a functioning implementation of a MPI routine, which works fine. In the process of making this a hybrid between MPI and shared memory, I am using pthreads. This in turn proofed the need of pthread_barriers.

But when I try to compile my code with the mpicc compiler, it complains over pthread_barrier_t and other barrier commands. If I remove these, and keep other threading parts it compiles just fine.

This is the line of code I insert to break the compilation:

```
pthread_barrier_t* barrier;
```

And for compilation I use:

```
mpicc -lm myprogram.c -o myprogram
```

The error returned from the compiler is:

```
myprogram.c:34: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

Where line 34 corresponds to what I wrote above.

[Edit] I am runnings this on Ubuntu 9.10, with the following gcc/mpicc compiler:
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1.
[/Edit]

Does anyone know what could be wrong and how I can make it compile?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_barrier_t` is part of the ADVANCED REALTIME THREAD option, so it might not be available on your system.
BTW, if you pose such a specific question you should always mention OS, version number and things like that.

Comment: Ok. How do I find out, wheter this is a part of my system or not - and if not, how do I get support for it, and can I?

I have added os and compiler version to my questing. Thanks!

Comment: yes on ubuntu it should be in. do `man pthread_barrier_wait` to know the includes you need to specify etc

Comment: Ah, also you should give the error that gcc gives you. I vaguely remember that in some version you could not call a variable `barrier` because they had defined a macro by that name in some system includes. Perhaps rename it to something else just to see.

Answer (score 1):

This means that `pthread_barrier_t` type is not in scope. Have you `#include`'d `pthread.h`?

Comment: Can you provide some minimal example of the code which doesn't compile?
Cause this one compiles perfectly:

#include <pthread.h>

int main () {
    pthread_barrier_t* barrier;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Which compiler? and on what system? That wouldn't compile on my system using mpicc..

Comment: Wow. Does it produce the same error message? Does it compile using pure gcc, not mpicc?
Mine is Debian Squeeze, gcc 4.4.4, and MPICH2 1.2.1.1. I also tried it on an Ubuntu 9.04 box, gcc 4.3.3 (but without mpicc), also ok.

Comment: Sorry Roman, I was a bit quick there. It does indeed compile - just missed the stdlib :)

I will try to make a larger small scale example of my code, to see when it breaks...

Comment: I reduced it, and found out it is actually the "std=c99" option that makes it fail... The above mentioned:
#include <pthread.h> int main () { pthread_barrier_t* barrier; return 0; }
Cannot compile with c99 - any idea why?

Comment: Use `gcc -std=c99 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600` to compile your source.